# How to decode strings in a data frame using R

Tags: r, string, parsing, utf-8, decode

I got a data frame with a column of string values where some of them seem to be encoded. See example below.

```
Joe<U+034F>Â¨l Potin; 
Sai<U+034F>Â¨d Slimani;   
JesÃºs Guerrero
```

How can I parse/decode them when i read the file?

I use R Studio and the function read.csv()

Comment: Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Thanks. Here are some examples:
Joe<U+034F>Â¨l Potin, 
Sai<U+034F>Â¨d Slimani, 
JesÃºs Guerrero

Comment: This looks like utf-8 interpreted as latin-? does `read.csv()` take en an encoding parameter? Or can you specify the encoding when you open the file?

Comment: Partially a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Example: `xx <- 'JesÃºs'; xx; Encoding(xx) <- 'UTF-8'; xx` returns `[1] "JesÃºs"` and `[1] "Jesús"`. However, the `Joe<U+034F>Â¨l` (or `Sai<U+034F>Â¨d`) data with `͏` (U+034F,  *Combining Grapheme Joiner*) seems to be garbled - I can't find a standard transformation to `Joël` (or`Saïd`).  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] (how and from where the data frame comes).

Answer (score 0):

If you have these strings already within R you have to bring the notation of the unicode character into an interpretable form, e.g. with a package like `stringi`. Using toy data here.

```
library(stringi)

source <- "word word <U+0218> other <U+0218> word"
source
[1] "word word <U+0218> other <U+0218> word"

# converting the string into "\uXXXX"
source_conv <- gsub(">","",gsub("<U\\+","\\\\u", source))
source_conv
[1] "word word \\u0218 other \\u0218 word"

# now interpreting the converted unicode character
stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(source_conv)
[1] "word word Ș other Ș word"
```

Ideally resolve these issues while generating the source strings to already do the conversion and use a proper encoding.